# Using RaspberryPi 3 with Pi-Camera and OpenCV to do PeopleCounting From the Top

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi3

I have been stuck for sometime now. Does anyone know of any links that can help me with using

**(Hardware)-** Raspberry Pi 3 connected to a Pi Cam ***NOT webcam***

Then using both hardware mentioned above i wan to use any available software I'm guessing openCV to do people counting from the top.

Example Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BszUJXLR2oA

Almost all available examples using the raspberry pi to do people counting from the top doesnt use the picam.. webcams are big and bulky. So if there is any tutorial or what available please help. Thank You

==========================================================================

What i tried:

So the problem I'm having is i have a sample code that uses openCV with a webcam.. instructions can be found here :https://www.hackster.io/deligence-technologies/person-counting-system-using-opencv-and-python-faf14f

And in this code it uses a usb webcam thus the line that i commented that says "#HERE i need to use the pi cam instead" that line is using cv2.VideoCapture(0).. i need to know how to use the picam instead. any ideas?

```
import argparse
import datetime
import imutils
import math

import cv2
import numpy as np

width = 800

textIn = 0
textOut = 0

def testIntersectionIn(x, y):

    res = -450 * x + 400 * y + 157500
    if((res >= -550) and  (res < 550)):
        print (str(res))
        return True
    return False



def testIntersectionOut(x, y):
    res = -450 * x + 400 * y + 180000
    if ((res >= -550) and (res <= 550)):
        print (str(res))
        return True

    return False

camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)              #HERE i need to use the pi cam instead

firstFrame = None


while True:

    (grabbed, frame) = camera.read()
    text = "Unoccupied"


    if not grabbed:
        break

    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=width)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (21, 21), 0)


    if firstFrame is None:
        firstFrame = gray
        continue


    frameDelta = cv2.absdiff(firstFrame, gray)
    thresh = cv2.threshold(frameDelta, 25, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

    thresh = cv2.dilate(thresh, None, iterations=2)
    _, cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    for c in cnts:
        if cv2.contourArea(c) < 12000:
            continue

        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

        cv2.line(frame, (width / 2, 0), (width, 450), (250, 0, 1), 2) #blue line
        cv2.line(frame, (width / 2 - 50, 0), (width - 50, 450), (0, 0, 255), 2)#red line


        rectagleCenterPont = ((x + x + w) /2, (y + y + h) /2)
        cv2.circle(frame, rectagleCenterPont, 1, (0, 0, 255), 5)

        if(testIntersectionIn((x + x + w) / 2, (y + y + h) / 2)):
            textIn += 1

        if(testIntersectionOut((x + x + w) / 2, (y + y + h) / 2)):
            textOut += 1

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

    cv2.putText(frame, "In: {}".format(str(textIn)), (10, 50),
                cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 255), 2)
    cv2.putText(frame, "Out: {}".format(str(textOut)), (10, 70),
                cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 255), 2)
    cv2.putText(frame, datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%A %d %B %Y %I:%M:%S%p"),
                (10, frame.shape[0] - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.35, (0, 0, 255), 1)
    cv2.imshow("Security Feed", frame)

camera.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Voting to close because you can just google this: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/03/30/accessing-the-raspberry-pi-camera-with-opencv-and-python/

Comment: i think u didn't read my question properly.. that link is one of the first few i saw... besides i already said i been stuck for sometime.. i obviously googled it first.. don't know still downvote no comments to you..

Comment: You don't actually ask a question, you ask for links to a problem you say you are stuck on but don't express the problem you are having. Read the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and ask a better, clearer question.

Comment: Ok edited to ask a question now any ideas?

Comment: I'm not quite sure, if this is going to work, cause I only used opencv with raspberry pi and webcams yet. But in `cv2.VideoCapture(0)` the 0 is for the camera port. I would try to change it to the Pi-Cam port, whatever it is. As mentioned I never used Pi-Cam

Comment: U haven’t tried but maybe it is possible? Or is there anyone that can tell me it is not possible? :/

Answer (score 1):

You say you read the link I posted in my comment but that is obviously not the case.

For clarity, [this tutorial shows you how to do what you want to do](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/03/30/accessing-the-raspberry-pi-camera-with-opencv-and-python/) and you need to read the code in the article and bring that into your code base.

What you are trying to do in your code is open the first USB webcam attached to your raspberry Pi. You do that on this line here:

```
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)              #HERE i need to use the pi cam instead
```

As your comment does indeed state.

What you need to do is instead use the PiCamera library, like this:

```
# import the necessary packages
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera
import time
import cv2

# initialize the camera and grab a reference to the raw camera capture
camera = PiCamera()
rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera)

# allow the camera to warmup
time.sleep(0.1)

# grab an image from the camera
camera.capture(rawCapture, format="bgr")
image = rawCapture.array

# display the image on screen and wait for a keypress
cv2.imshow("Image", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

The above example and tutorial should get you up and running with the basics, you can then modify the Hackster tutorial that you are following to use the PiCamera instead.

Comment: Sighs... I did read that post I even did try what u just did long ago.. but ur using the part5. single image when I tried from that website I used part6.referencing from video... the import part is the simplest ... once u run the code with the hackster code, u will realize that in the while true statement.. camera.read() will fail cause the pi module does not have a read() function... I have no idea how to intergrate both codes tgt that’s y I asked this question in the first place..

Comment: You don't use Camera.Read, you use # grab an image from the camera
camera.capture(rawCapture, format="bgr")
image = rawCapture.array

Comment: So you are trying to say,  (grabbed,frame) = camera.capture(rawCapture, format=“bgr”) ? The format is the same??

Comment: Should be, if you read in with `image = rawCapture.array` then you can pass that to OpenCV Functions such as Imshow with no issue. and BGR is the same format that Camera.Read returns

Comment: Ok I shall try it first thing in the morning tmr when I get back to the office :) hopefully it works! I’ll get back to u thanks

Comment: Ok i have tried but it failed. First question i need to ask you from the link you sent. Shld i use step 5 or step 6. Step 5 is image capture Step 6 is video capture

Comment: Lol you do realise u showed me step 5 and were talking about step5 the whole time.... anyways. It doesn't work with both step 5 or 6..  so ya..

Comment: You need to learn to read the entire tutorial, understand what it is saying and apply that learning to your code, just copy and pasting from websites won't really help you. "It may work" but if you haven't understood it it won't help you next time. Good luck but I won't be returning to this question.

Comment: So y don't you help if thats the case? YOUR ANSWER was a copy and paste from step 5 from another webpage. Do you even understand what u are typing GPPK. Sighs.. If you don't have the answer y come comment so much down vote and leave? *Round of applause*